# Combining uncertainties in replicate measurements

Tags: mean, repeated-measures, measurement-error, uncertainty

I recently got some Uranium–Thorium dates back from a lab. They are reported with a ±2σ uncertainty. Several of the measurements are replicates from the same specimen. That is, a few pieces from a single rock (a single annual layer from a speleothem, by definition deposited during the same year) were analysed on the same instrument.

My understanding of statistics is quite limited, but I know mean of the measurements should approach the true age (assuming no systematic error) as the number of measurements increases. If I want to summarise my results, what is the appropriate way to treat the uncertainty? Or perhaps this is not the best way to think of these results.

| Age (ka) | ±2s |
| --- | --- |
| 11.7 | 0.85 |
| 12.4 | 0.39 |
| 11.2 | 0.76 |
| **mean: 11.8** | **??** |

Please enlighten me!

Comment: Some principles are laid out [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/314938/919).  [This related post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/434532/919) provides an answer.  However, under your assumptions [the mean should be computed as a *weighted* arithmetic mean of the three measurements,](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/12255/919) using the inverse squared margins of error as the weights.  This gives much more weight to 12.4, resulting in $12.08$ for your estimate and $0.48$ for its margin of error.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense! I spent some time going through related questions, but missed that one. Thanks heaps!